# Decompose vector c by vectors a, b and a×b. Calculate the angle

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

> The given vectors are $\vec a$=$\vec i$ + $\vec j$ − $\vec k$ ,  $\vec b$=−2$\vec i$−$\vec j$+2$\vec k$ $\vec c$ =$\vec i$−$\vec j$ + 2$\vec k$. a.) Decompose vector $\vec c$ into components by vectors $\vec a$, $\vec b$ and $\vec a$×$\vec b$.
> b.) Calculate the angle formed by vector $\vec c$ with the plane defined by vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$.

---

I dont know where to start, I think for task a.) vector c should be:

$\vec{c} = \alpha\vec{a}+\beta\vec{b}+\gamma(\vec{a}x\vec{b})   $

I would appreciate any help in solving this problem.

Comment: try taking dot products with vector b and a on both sides

Comment: Can You please clarify that? @AadiSinha

Comment: the vectors are known hence the dot products of each of the vectors are known, alpha and beta are the only unknown variables, we have two equations hence we can solve for them, plug alpha, beta in main equation, we have gamma (one variable one equation)